# Not able to get the lombok features in STS

Tags: spring-boot, lombok

I am using `STS` on `windows`. I have added `lombok.jar` into my project.

I have access to the annotations but the getters and setters aren't generated. I get the same errors I would get if I tried accessing a getter or setter method that doesn't exist. What could I be missing?

**Here are the code snips**

**Bean:**

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String location;

}
```

**Pom.xml:**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lombok is a code generator. It doesn't need to be included as part of your built target, as such it should be included in your maven as a [provided dependency](https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.20</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

You also need to make sure the annotation processor is setup to run as part of the maven build. (Also in the above link)

I don't use eclipse, but you probably also want to install the [lombok plugin for eclipse](https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse) so that eclipse knows the getters and setters are not in the code files but will be generated.